# Image.width and Image.height equal to 0 after I load images (javascript)

Tags: javascript, image

I tried multiple times to assign my image.width and image.height to another variable but the value of the variable is always 0.

This is my code:

```
//canvas element
var canvas = document.createElement ('canvas');
var canvasWidth = window.innerWidth ;
var canvasHeight = window.innerHeight;
canvas.width = canvasWidth;
canvas.height = canvasHeight;

//img element
var loadImage = function (src, scale){
    var image = document.createElement ('img');
    image.onload = function(){
        image.width*=scale;
        image.height*=scale;
    }
    image.src=src;
    return image;
}

//player function
var Player = function (){
    this.image = loadImage("Fish1.png", 1);
    this.score = 0;
    this.width = this.image.width;
    this.height = this.image.height;
    this.x = window.innerWidth/2;
    this.y= window.innerHeight/2;
}

Player.prototype.update = function (){
}

Player.prototype.render = function (){
    //context.drawImage(this.image, this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
}


//context
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

//player object
var player = new Player ();

window.onload = function (){
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    //context.drawImage(player.image, player.x, player.y, 100, 100);
}
```

as u can see, after I did some google searches, I found that I had to first load my images using image.onload, and I did that but I still cannot assign the value of image.width. For example if I put document.write(player.width) or even document.write(player.image.width) the value 0 is printed. But then I tried printing out player.image.width in window.onload function and it prints out the correct value. Can you please tell me what I am missing and how I can solve this problem.

Comment: You are accessing the image's dimensions **before** it loaded. Simply adding `onload` does not solve your problem. You still have to access the dimensions *after* the image loaded.

Comment: so how would I load it. I thought that my loadImage function returns a loaded image?

Comment: All that `image.onload = function() { ...}` does is tell the browser "please execute this function when the image loaded". The `return image;` statement will still be executed *before* the image loaded. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086/218196 for more info.

Comment: Thank-you for the suggestion. It seems I didn't search enough. I am looking through the article now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are still accessing the image's dimensions **before** it loaded. Simply adding `onload` does not solve your problem. You still have to access the dimensions *after* the image loaded

---

One solution would be to load the images first and then create player objects with the image.

You can have a static method which provides a nice API:

```
function Player(image) {
    this.image = image;
    // ...
}

Player.withImage = function(src, scale, done) {
    var image = document.createElement('img');
    image.onload = function(){
        image.width *= scale;
        image.height *= scale;
        // once the image loaded, we create a new player and pass it to the callback
        done(new Player(image));
    };
    image.src = src;
};

Player.withImage("Fish1.png", 1, function(player) {
   // context.drawImage(player.image, player.x, player.y, 100, 100);
});
```

Of course this is a very simple example for a single player. You can keep the image loading code separate from the player class. If you have multiple images to load, you might want to look into [**promises**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).